# Python tests pass on cmd and fail on VS2012

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012, numpy, nose, ptvs

I'm setting up Python (CPython 3.4, 64-bit) on a new machine (Windows 10). I installed numpy & nose, and ran numpy.test() through the interpreter prompt to make sure everything's working as expected:

```
Running unit tests for numpy
NumPy version 1.9.0
NumPy is installed in C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy
Python version 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:16:31) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
nose version 1.3.4

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5162 tests in 36.783s

OK (KNOWNFAIL=10, SKIP=20)
```

So far so good, but when I do the same thing through PTVS on VS2012 (my team uses TFS for source control), there are errors and test failures (below):

```
Running unit tests for numpy
NumPy version 1.9.0
NumPy is installed in C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy
Python version 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:16:31) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
nose version 1.3.4

======================================================================
ERROR: test_basic (test_multiarray.TestResize)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\tests\test_multiarray.py", line 2850, in test_basic
    x.resize((5, 5))
ValueError: cannot resize an array that references or is referenced
by another array in this way.  Use the resize function

======================================================================
ERROR: test_freeform_shape (test_multiarray.TestResize)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\tests\test_multiarray.py", line 2880, in test_freeform_shape
    x.resize(3, 2, 1)
ValueError: cannot resize an array that references or is referenced
by another array in this way.  Use the resize function

======================================================================
ERROR: test_int_shape (test_multiarray.TestResize)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\tests\test_multiarray.py", line 2862, in test_int_shape
    x.resize(3)
ValueError: cannot resize an array that references or is referenced
by another array in this way.  Use the resize function

======================================================================
ERROR: test_obj_obj (test_multiarray.TestResize)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\tests\test_multiarray.py", line 2892, in test_obj_obj
    a.resize(15,)
ValueError: cannot resize an array that references or is referenced
by another array in this way.  Use the resize function

======================================================================
ERROR: test_zeros_appended (test_multiarray.TestResize)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\tests\test_multiarray.py", line 2885, in test_zeros_appended
    x.resize(2, 3, 3)
ValueError: cannot resize an array that references or is referenced
by another array in this way.  Use the resize function

======================================================================
ERROR: Ticket #950
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\tests\test_regression.py", line 1272, in test_blasdot_uninitialized_memory
    x.resize((m, 0))
ValueError: cannot resize an array that references or is referenced
by another array in this way.  Use the resize function

======================================================================
FAIL: test_blasdot.test_dot_3args
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\tests\test_blasdot.py", line 54, in test_dot_3args
    assert_equal(sys.getrefcount(r), 2)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\utils.py", line 334, in assert_equal
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError:
Items are not equal:
 ACTUAL: 3
 DESIRED: 2

======================================================================
FAIL: test_1d (test_indexing.TestMultiIndexingAutomated)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\tests\test_indexing.py", line 940, in test_1d
    self._check_single_index(a, index)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\tests\test_indexing.py", line 859, in _check_single_index
    self._compare_index_result(arr, index, mimic_get, no_copy)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\tests\test_indexing.py", line 875, in _compare_index_result
    assert_equal(sys.getrefcount(arr), 3)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\utils.py", line 334, in assert_equal
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError:
Items are not equal:
 ACTUAL: 4
 DESIRED: 3

======================================================================
FAIL: test_multidim (test_indexing.TestMultiIndexingAutomated)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\tests\test_indexing.py", line 922, in test_multidim
    self._check_multi_index(self.a, index)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\tests\test_indexing.py", line 836, in _check_multi_index
    self._compare_index_result(arr, index, mimic_get, no_copy)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\tests\test_indexing.py", line 875, in _compare_index_result
    assert_equal(sys.getrefcount(arr), 3)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\utils.py", line 334, in assert_equal
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError:
Items are not equal:
 ACTUAL: 4
 DESIRED: 3

======================================================================
FAIL: test_dot_3args (test_multiarray.TestDot)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\tests\test_multiarray.py", line 3285, in test_dot_3args
    assert_equal(sys.getrefcount(r), 2)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\utils.py", line 334, in assert_equal
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError:
Items are not equal:
 ACTUAL: 3
 DESIRED: 2

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5162 tests in 181.506s

FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=10, SKIP=20, errors=6, failures=4)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I ran the script that I wrote in VS through the command line, and the results were the same as running the test through the interpreter directly, so I'm confident there's something amiss in my VS/Python setup rather than the script itself. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing amiss in your setup. It's just that numpy tests seem to be fragile in a sense that they don't tolerate debuggers. I'm not sure what's going on there, but it seems that tests involving `sys.getrefcount`, and semantics that depend on it being something specifically (usually just having a single reference to an array) are what's failing.

You can repro this when running the interpreter directly by registering your own trace function with `sys.settrace`, e.g.:

```
import sys
def trace_func(f, e, a):
    return trace_func
sys.settrace(trace_func)

import numpy
numpy.test()
```

Note that you can run the script from VS without debugging it via Debug -> Start Without Debugging. This will give you results identical to running the interpreter directly.